# Is it possible to run RSYNC as root on a remote server while connecting with a different user?

Tags: logging, server, root, rsync

I am wanting to backup my server logs (/var/log/httpd/) to my local disk at home.  The problem is that the log directory is owned by accounts that specifically cannot SSH into the machine.

I can SSH into the remote machine using my regular account and then I can sudo to access those logs files.  Is there a way I can run RSYNC from my home machine, but have it run as root so that it has the permissions required to access those log files and send them back to me?

A typical example (run from my local machine at home):

```
rsync -avz [user]@[server]:/var/log/httpd/* ./logs
```

Obviously that would work if [user]'s account had permissions to access /var/log/httpd/, but it does not (and I'd rather not give that account permissions).

So I'm wondering if there is some other command I could inject into the middle of that RSYNC request that will ultimately force the remote user to operate as root even though the login is through [user]?

I should also note that I don't want to run it backwards.  In other words, I realize I could log into the remote machine, switch to root, and then run RSYNC the other way.  The problem is that I don't want to configure the home machine to accept a remote login for a variety of reasons.  So I'd only want to pull the files down, not send them up, so to speak.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not copy the log files into a directory that you have access to and own?

Comment: I could definitely do that, yes.  I was just hoping to be able to automate the process entirely from my local end without having to affect the remote server.

If it's absolutely not possible then yes, setting up a script on the remote server that moves them into a directory I own would certainly take care of the problem.  As as RSYNC will preserve the files, once they're deleted from that temp location, I'd still have them.   I just thought that perhaps there was a way to accomplish the goal without having to create a middle step.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways, to ahive that what you want.

1st: use rsyncd on remote host and add to it config file (/etc/rsyncd.conf):

```
[httpd_logs]
uid=0
gid=0
read only = yes
path = /var/log/httpd/
```

save changes and start rsyncd.
Then, on local machine run:

`rsync -avz remote_server::httpd_logs/* ./logs`

2nd: based on answers which I found on stackoverflow and this kinds of portal

Create helper file:

```
cat > ssh_sudo << 'EOF'
{
  echo $sudoPWD;
  cat - ;
} | ssh -A $* &
EOF
chmod u+x ssh_sudo
```

and then use it together with rsync:

`read -s -p "Sudo password: " sudoPWD; rsync -aAHe ./ssh_sudo --rsync-path "sudo -S 2> /dev/null rsync" remote_norootuser@remote_host:/var/log/httpd/* ./logs/`

Of course, "remote_norootuser" must have sudo privileges on "remote_host".